# Как убрать скролл в мобильной версии

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, как убрать скролл в chrome
 на этой странице [ссылка](http://landing.web-devsoltan.com/)

не могу догнать как убрать, смотрел через firefox нету скролла.

Answer (score 1):

У вас

```
.left_col {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 85px;
    width: 600px;
}
```

или делайте его на моб. устройствах `width: 100%;`

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
 .left_col {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 85px;
    width: 100%;
 }
}
```

или сделайте по-умолчанию

```
.left_col {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 85px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
}
```

пробуйте, что больше подойдет

Comment: там еще у него ошибки есть, вообще шаблон кривой

Comment: Ну то уже второй вопрос, главное чтоб он понимал суть своей проблемы

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему таким образом  в каждом блоке есть **wrapper** я добавил свойство 
**overflow: hidden;** и все встало на свои места